# JavaScript: Formdata append null value - NumberFormatException

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc, form-data

The following client code

```
FormData formData = FormData(document.getElementById(formElemId));
formData.append('version', null);
```

when received in Server Side via Spring MVC as below

```
@RequestParam(value = 'version', required = false) Integer versionNumber
```

throws the following exception

**Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by adding `defaultValue` like below.

```
@RequestParam(value = "version", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer versionNumber
```

see [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot set a default value to the version (Application Logic). I'll have to handle the null in client itself. So I was wondering what turns my null object in client to string null when received in server.

Comment: actually it was a bug in previous versions which has been resolved now...try with latest versions defaultValue is not needed.

Comment: Oh thanks for that. Can you please let me know on which version is this bug was fixed. Am currently on 4.3.9

Comment: This was considered a bug in 2013: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10180

and was fixed with version 3.2.2. Problem shouldn't occur in any versions after that and your code should work just fine.

Comment: With the latest spring boot, if I use `@ModelAttribute`, this exception still exist