# Spring - Handling null values in Request Parameters

Tags: java, spring, null, request, http-request-parameters

In Spring (4.3.9):

A Request param sent from client as null to server, the null object is getting treated as string null in the request when obtained via request-param like:

```
@RequestParam(value = key, required = false) Integer key
```

As for as the solution goes, I can handle this via client and prevent the null from being passed in the first place and I couldn't get a clear solution from this ([JavaScript: Formdata append null value - NumberFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205938/javascript-formdata-append-null-value-numberformatexception)).

Can anyone please help me out as to what class or method in spring framework does this conversion from a null object to string null.

Comment: You're looking for `HttpMessageConverter` and the `Converter` framework generally, but you haven't really described enough of your case to understand if there's an underlying problem (for example, it's not clear whether you mean `s == null` or `s.equals("null")`). Including an actual HTTP request would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the content you provide for the `@RequestParam` by default it will treat as string, that is the reason `null` is treating as `"null"` string. In the spring framework the `Converter<S, R>` and `ConverterFactory<S, R>` will convert from `String` to corresponding type.

You can write custom converter and add it to spring registry [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder)

```
public class StringToIntegerConverter implements Converter<String, Integer> {

@Override
public Integer convert(String from) {
    // custom logic
   }
}
```

register

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new StringToIntegerConverter());
       }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.The converter you pointed out converts the string to the desired type mentioned in the @RequestParam, but can you point me where does the null object passed from client is getting converted to string null.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I could see that when i do request.getParameter("key") it return me string null ("null") in my first filter itself. So am assuming this conversion happens in the apache http layer. I just need to know the class file , method that parses this.

Comment: i'm not sure to that point, may be front controller is the main point of request

Comment: Thanks for the prompt help. I'll just handle this client to avoid issues for now and also i'll keep this open for better explanation.